# how do i make a gif change when I click it?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, gif

so I'm making a website/ profile where I wanted to include a small section where you can talk to a character.

So the character is a gif and when you click it it changes to a different gif of the character looking at you and saying something.
Then you click them again to the conclusion of what they where saying.
Then clicking again would take you back to the first gif

I have a few 1 loop gifs, I was wondering if I could play them when they appear instead of hiding them from the start so that when they appear nothing is moving. also is it possible to have certain gifs take over in a certain amount of time?

like i have a gif that only loops once and i intend that to happen and as soon as that gif finishes another one will take its place

```
<div id="first" >

<img id="gif1" src="https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/e281ef83-45fa-4d46-8aae-2c5d69f8f26f/df3m6vm-720538cd-7ef2-45b1-a74e-14356c7ddb28.gif?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7InBhdGgiOiJcL2ZcL2UyODFlZjgzLTQ1ZmEtNGQ0Ni04YWFlLTJjNWQ2OWY4ZjI2ZlwvZGYzbTZ2bS03MjA1MzhjZC03ZWYyLTQ1YjEtYTc0ZS0xNDM1NmM3ZGRiMjguZ2lmIn1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmZpbGUuZG93bmxvYWQiXX0.L_vLqsqCUKYBsFA7sMS4Z3j8_aD9dFL7L9Ov81L75rg" 
alt="gif1" 
style="max-width:30%;
position:fixed;
top:5px;
left:5px;
z-index:3;" >

<img id="gif2" src="https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/e281ef83-45fa-4d46-8aae-2c5d69f8f26f/df3m6vh-02518610-cc30-4eda-a43c-4238075f2414.gif?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7InBhdGgiOiJcL2ZcL2UyODFlZjgzLTQ1ZmEtNGQ0Ni04YWFlLTJjNWQ2OWY4ZjI2ZlwvZGYzbTZ2aC0wMjUxODYxMC1jYzMwLTRlZGEtYTQzYy00MjM4MDc1ZjI0MTQuZ2lmIn1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmZpbGUuZG93bmxvYWQiXX0.4CLnQ-I1S3BcBaqYqB3ulGPvC3RS3gpfFXzOYbbwCUs" 
alt="gif2" 
style="max-width:30%;
position:fixed;
top:5px;
left:5px;
z-index:3;" >

<img id="gif3" src="https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/e281ef83-45fa-4d46-8aae-2c5d69f8f26f/df3m6ve-c0fc705a-d82f-4a2f-937b-3354f119c4eb.gif?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7InBhdGgiOiJcL2ZcL2UyODFlZjgzLTQ1ZmEtNGQ0Ni04YWFlLTJjNWQ2OWY4ZjI2ZlwvZGYzbTZ2ZS1jMGZjNzA1YS1kODJmLTRhMmYtOTM3Yi0zMzU0ZjExOWM0ZWIuZ2lmIn1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmZpbGUuZG93bmxvYWQiXX0.G9tRsjqpgwV6oeUxNJ-8aCWmZfB6Bx5-vuJjxEsZO9A" 
alt="gif3" 
style="max-width:30%;
position:fixed;
top:5px;
left:5px;
z-index:3;" >

<img id="gif4" src="https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/e281ef83-45fa-4d46-8aae-2c5d69f8f26f/df3m6v6-4f4f7624-ca9e-44dc-a6e2-fe8ba89075b4.gif?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7InBhdGgiOiJcL2ZcL2UyODFlZjgzLTQ1ZmEtNGQ0Ni04YWFlLTJjNWQ2OWY4ZjI2ZlwvZGYzbTZ2Ni00ZjRmNzYyNC1jYTllLTQ0ZGMtYTZlMi1mZThiYTg5MDc1YjQuZ2lmIn1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmZpbGUuZG93bmxvYWQiXX0.bjE1Dhm1Jgp7sEEHO5unc7d6KRRNZat2Slsy-B3IsC8" 
alt="gif4" 
style="max-width:30%;
position:fixed;
top:5px;
left:5px;
z-index:3;" >

<img id="gif5" src="https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/e281ef83-45fa-4d46-8aae-2c5d69f8f26f/df3m6v9-06bccbcf-e0ec-4012-a27a-abadd0c56e1a.gif?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7InBhdGgiOiJcL2ZcL2UyODFlZjgzLTQ1ZmEtNGQ0Ni04YWFlLTJjNWQ2OWY4ZjI2ZlwvZGYzbTZ2OS0wNmJjY2JjZi1lMGVjLTQwMTItYTI3YS1hYmFkZDBjNTZlMWEuZ2lmIn1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmZpbGUuZG93bmxvYWQiXX0.jUpcK5Tn8BWGj_ioH_aM3Zt6RdegiEg_75yiV7uFd0o" 
alt="gif5" 
style="max-width:30%;
position:fixed;
top:5px;
left:5px;
z-index:3;" >

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#gif2').hide();
    $('#gif3').hide();
    $('#gif4').hide();
    $('#gif5').hide();

    

    $('#first').on('click', function() {
        $('#gif1').toggle();
        $('#gif3').toggle();
    });

    


});
</script>

</div>
```

sorry about the spaghetti code

Answer (score 0):

Use `id=` to give your gif elements an id, then use jQuery to change, hide or show the gif that is displayed using something like this:
`$("#gif").attr("src", "src.gif");`